# anchoring an absolute path to parent directory in shared repo

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, pytest, absolute-path

I'm working on a shared repo and am using pytest through pycharm and have a test directory structure looking something like this:

```
├── data
│   ├── sample_data.json
│   ├── real_data.json
│   └── __init__.py
├── my_project
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── main.py
└── tests
    ├── conftest.py
    ├── test0.py
    ├── test_class1
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── test1.py
    │   ├── test2.py
    │   └── test3.py
    └── test_class2
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── test4.py
        ├── test5.py
        └── test6.py
```

My conftest propagates the sample data using something like this:

```
# conftest.py
from pathlib import Path

data_path = Path("/home/myusername/projects/my_project/data") # the problem line
sample_data = data_path.joinpath("sample_data.json") # json filetype is irrelevant

propagate_data(sample_data)
```

This works great and allows me to call pytest from any level of the test directory and the tests find the data properly. However it's not acceptable in a shared repo because the absolute path is unique to my system.  I've tried using relative paths, but the way Pycharm invokes pytest I get a `FileNotFound` unless I only run tests from the top-level `test/` directory.

What is the preferred way to use the `Path` or `os.pathlib.abspath` modules to always be able to find `sample_data.json` regardless of from which directory python3 was called?  Or, to put it another way, can you dynamically create absolute paths that are relative a project root?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use your `conftest.py` location as the base for the path calculation (provided its location is fixed relative to the project root):

```py
conftest_path = Path(__file__)
data_path = conftest_path.parent.parent / 'data'
```